# Updating the coordinates of the child element after scaling

Tags: javascript, html

When I scale the entire div and start moving the image in this div, it moves abruptly from the mouse to the left or right (depending on the zoom level), but if I release the image and try to move it again, it does not bounce. How can I fix this?
I think the problem is here somewhere:

```
function setTransform(element, pointX, pointY) {
    element.style.transform = "translate(" + pointX + "px, " + pointY + "px) scale(" + scale + ")";
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    ...
    activeImage.dataset.pointX = e.clientX - activeImage.startX;
    activeImage.dataset.pointY = e.clientY - activeImage.startY;
    setTransform(activeImage, parseInt(activeImage.dataset.pointX / scale), parseInt(activeImage.dataset.pointY / scale));
}

function handleWheel(e) {
    var delta = (e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta : -e.deltaY);
    if (delta > 0 && scale < maxScale) {
        scale *= 1.2;
    } else if (delta < 0 && scale > minScale) {
        scale /= 1.2;
    }
```

```js
/* Установить ширину боковой панели шириной 250 пикселей и следующий и левом поле содержание страницы шириной 250 пикселей и следующий */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
}
/* Установите ширину боковой панели на 0, а левое поле содержимого страницы - на 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
}


////////Выбор плана
document.getElementById('imageInput').addEventListener('change', handleImageSelect);

function handleImageSelect(event) {
    const fileInput = event.target;
    const files = fileInput.files;

    if (files.length > 0) {
        const selectedImage = files[0];
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage);
        document.getElementById('canvas-cameras').style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
    }
}

function changeBackground() {
    document.getElementById('imageInput').click();
}

var scale = 1,
    images = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-image'),
    activeImage = null,
    minScale = 0.7,
    maxScale = 2,
    panning = false;

function setTransform(element, pointX, pointY) {
    element.style.transform = "translate(" + pointX + "px, " + pointY + "px) scale(" + scale + ")";
}

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = e.target;
    if (target.classList.contains('draggable-image')) {
        activeImage = target;
        activeImage.startX = e.clientX - parseInt(activeImage.dataset.pointX || 0);
        activeImage.startY = e.clientY - parseInt(activeImage.dataset.pointY || 0);
        panning = true;
    }
}

function handleMouseUp() {
    panning = false;
    activeImage = null;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!panning || !activeImage) {
        return;
    }

    activeImage.dataset.pointX = e.clientX - activeImage.startX;
    activeImage.dataset.pointY = e.clientY - activeImage.startY;
    setTransform(activeImage, parseInt(activeImage.dataset.pointX / scale),         parseInt(activeImage.dataset.pointY / scale));
}

function handleWheel(e) {
    var delta = (e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta : -e.deltaY);

    if (delta > 0 && scale < maxScale) {
        scale *= 1.2;
    } else if (delta < 0 && scale > minScale) {
        scale /= 1.2;
    }

    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvas-cameras');
    var xs = (e.clientX - parseInt(canvasDiv.dataset.pointX)) / scale,
        ys = (e.clientY - parseInt(canvasDiv.dataset.pointY)) / scale;
    canvasDiv.dataset.pointX = e.clientX - xs * scale;
    canvasDiv.dataset.pointY = e.clientY - ys * scale;
    setTransform(canvasDiv, parseInt(canvasDiv.dataset.pointX), parseInt(canvasDiv.dataset.pointY));
}

document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown, { passive: false });
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove, { passive: false });
document.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel, { passive: false });

var imageCounter = 1;

document.getElementById('addCamera').addEventListener('click', function () {
    showImage();
});

function showImage() {
    var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvas-cameras');

    imgElement.src = 'https://30.img.avito.st/image/1/1._DJTzra2UNtFburbJ_2oIZJtUNHtzVFh521S.o30giUQW-wMG3ar610UkHqINEtoYfC7c5jPPw6qYZxQ';
    imgElement.alt = 'Картинка ' + imageCounter;
    imgElement.className = 'draggable-image';

    imgElement.style.position = 'relative';
    imgElement.style.top = '20%';
    imgElement.style.left = '20%';
    imgElement.style.height = '20px';
    imgElement.style.width = '20px';

    var uniqueId = 'image' + imageCounter;
    imgElement.id = uniqueId;

    canvasDiv.appendChild(imgElement);

    // Добавляем новую картинку в массив изображений
    images = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-image');

    // Устанавливаем начальные координаты для новой картинки
    imgElement.dataset.pointX = 0;
    imgElement.dataset.pointY = 0;

    // Увеличиваем счетчик изображений
    imageCounter++;
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn-link.nav-link:focus, .form-control:focus, .form-check-input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem white, 0 0 0 0.25rem #258cfb;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.button_change {
    position: absolute;
}

.container {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.footer {
    background-color: white;
}

#image_input {
    display: none;
}

.draggable-image {
    z-index: -1;
    transform-origin: left top;
    cursor: grab;
}

#canvas-cameras {
    background-image: url('https://www.ok-t.ru/studopediaru/baza12/617229321060.files/image001.png');
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transform-origin: left top;
    position: absolute;
    /*transform: scale(0.8);*/
    cursor: grab;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: -100;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* Меню бокового бара */
.sidebar {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Полный рост */
    width: 0; /* 0 ширина - измените это с помощью JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Оставаться на месте */
    z-index: 1; /* Оставайтесь на вершине */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Черный */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Отключить горизонтальную прокрутку */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Поместите содержимое 60px сверху */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 секунд эффект перехода для скольжения в боковой панели */
}

    /* На боковой панели */
    .sidebar a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

        /* При наведении курсора мыши на навигационные ссылки измените их цвет */
        .sidebar a:hover {
            color: #f1f1f1;
        }

    /* Положение и стиль кнопки закрытия (верхний правый угол) */
    .sidebar .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

/* Кнопка для открытия бокового бара */
.openbtn {
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #111;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: none;
}

    .openbtn:hover {
        background-color: #444;
    }

/* Стиль содержимого страницы - используйте это, если вы хотите переместить содержимое страницы вправо при открытии боковой навигации */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s; /* Если вы хотите эффект перехода */
    padding: 20px;
}

/* На небольших экранах, где высота меньше 450px, измените стиль sidebar (меньше отступов и меньший размер шрифта) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidebar {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

        .sidebar a {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Map Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="button_change openbtn" onclick="openNav()" type="button">Edit</button>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <button id="addCamera"><img src="https://30.img.avito.st/image/1/1._DJTzra2UNtFburbJ_2oIZJtUNHtzVFh521S.o30giUQW-wMG3ar610UkHqINEtoYfC7c5jPPw6qYZxQ" width="50" height="50"></button>
    <input type="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/*">
    <button type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">изменить план</button>
</div>
 <div class="draggable-image" id="canvas-cameras"></div>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Clicking on Edit opens a menu where I select the item I want to place on the map, for example, a camera.
I'm trying to make something like a canvas where I can place my elements, move them and change the zoom of the entire canvas.

Comment: My guess is that you would need to reset something after changing the scale. Would it be possible to create a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), which illustrates the problem?

Comment: @FiddlingAway added code snippet.